# Cómo crear un modelo de un product feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, base-de-datos

Una pregunta. Estoy intentando modelar un alimentador de productos de mis proveedores.

Lo que se quiere es sincronizar en tiempo real nuevos productos, stocks de todos los productos y productos que se descontinúan por parte de los distribuidores.

Hay n distribuidores. Cada uno con sus productos que en muchos casos pueden coincidir con productos de otros distribuidores.

En ese caso quiero poder tener acceso al stock de ese producto por distribuidor.

Estaba pensando en generar una tabla por distribuidor pero eso puede ser repetitivo. Cómo la puedo diseñar para que teniendo una sola tabla de productos y otra de distribuidores pueda manejar stocks separados por sku por distribuidor.

Comment: No entiendo cual es tu problema. Tienes una tabla de distribuidores y una tabla de productos que tiene un `distribuidor_id`, luego en la tabla de productos puedes crear todos los productos que sean, independiente que estén repetidos o no entre distribuidores, no hay una limitante a menos que tu mismo crees alguna restricción. Creo que estás perdiéndote algo en la pregunta, si la editas, mejor.

Comment: La pregunta es... cómo puedo tener el stock por distribuidor separado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que describes es una relación *muchos a michos*, donde un distribuidor puede tener muchos productos y un producto puede pertenecer a muchos distribuidores.

Para modelar esta relación necesitas 3 tablas:

- Productos
- Distribuidores
- Inventarios (aquí guardarás el *stock*)

Y podrías modelarlo en rails de la siguiente forma:

```
class Producto < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :inventarios
  has_many :distribuidores, through: :inventarios
end

class Inventario < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :producto
  belongs_to :distribuidor
end

class Distribuidor < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "distribuidores"

  has_many :inventarios
  has_many :productos, through: :inventarios
end
```

Tus migraciones se verían así:

```
class CreateProductos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :productos do |t|
      t.string :sku
      t.string :nombre
      t.string :descripcion

      # otros campos de producto
    end
  end
end

class CreateInventario < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :inventarios do |t|
      t.integer :producto_id
      t.integer :distribuidor_id
      t.integer :stock
    end
  end
end

class CreateDistribuidores < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :distribuidores do |t|
      t.string :nombre
      t.string :direccion

      # otros campos de distribuidor
    end
  end
end
```

Lo más importante es el campo `stock` de la tabla `inventarios` ya que ahí guardarás las unidades disponibles de cada producto para cada distribuidor.

Para actualizar un inventario, por ejemplo el del producto `1` para el distribuidor `1`, harías lo siguiente:

```
Inventario.find_by(producto_id: 1, distribuidor_id: 1).update(stock: 5)
```

O bien, si quieres obtener el stock de todos los productos de un distribuidor (e.g. distribuidor con `id = 1`), podrías hacer los siguiente:

```
@inventarios = Distribuidor.find(1).inventarios
```

Esto te regresará una colección (objeto `ActiveRecord::Relation`), la cual puedes iterar para leer cada `stock`; por ejemplo (en  tu vista):

```
<ul>
  <% @inventarios.each |i| %>
    <li><%= i.producto.nombre %>: <%= i.stock %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```